# Impatiently wait for input

Tags: code-golf, interactive, concurrency

Your task today is to implement a time limit for getting input, a task I've found rather annoying to achieve in most languages.

You will create a program function which prompts the user for input. Immediatly after the user supplies input, print the message `input received` and end execution/return. However, if the user waits for more than 10 seconds to provide input, output the message `no input received` and end execution/return.

Input must be from `stdin` (the console) or equivalent, not function or program arguments, however output can be either to `stdout`, your function's return value, or any other accepted output method.

You may ask for any amount of  input, it can be a single character, a line, a word, or whatever method is shortest in your language as long as it waits for at least one character.

You must output as soon as the input is received, not after the 10 seconds have passed.

After 10 seconds have passed, you *must* end, you cannot continue waiting for input after `no input received` has been printed.

You may assume that input is not passed in the time between 10 seconds elapsing and text being printed to the screen, as this is an extremely small window. You may also assume that your language's builtin equivalent of `sleep` is consistently, absolutely perfect.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: +1 just for the nice touch to prevent golfing languages from using their dictionary. Oh, and great challenge too.

Comment: @Adám unless your language has a builtin read with timeout, I think the only good way to do this is OS/Thread magic, which most golfing languages can't do anyway.

Comment: Now I have to rewrite my program. Was almost ready to post... ;-)

Comment: What's the allowance either side of the 10 second wait period? I've assumed `+-0.1` at the moment.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You can assume your language's equivalent of `sleep` functions perfectly 100% of the time.

Comment: @Phoenix I ask because there is a small race condition in my code, that in reality will probably never get hit but it is possible.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No, that's fine.

Comment: Some languages can't read from STDIN (e.g. [Applescript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125368/11259)).  Do they get a waiver?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yes, the restriction was intended to prevent reading from args, where the challenge doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would love to see a Python answer to this.

Comment: @Lembik Mego came up with one in chat, you can ask him about it.

Comment: How long does the input we take have to be? Could it be, say, 1 character?

Comment: @ScottMilner yes, read the question

Comment: @Lembik There you go, a Python answer.

Comment: @Adám: I'm working on a golfing language string compressor that makes use of real-world input to work out which words are most common. It's not released yet, but I checked the dictionary; amazingly, `recieved` is actually in there (at a similar frequency to words like `businesswoman`, `microfossils`, and `putrescine`).

Comment: Phoenix, could you let me know if [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125540/58974) is valid? I'm not 100% convinced meself!

Comment: @Shaggy yep, seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### bash, 38 bytes

```sh
read -t10||a=no;echo $a input received
```

This uses the `-t` (timeout) option to bash's `read`, which causes it to fail and return a nonzero exit code if no input is given in the specified number of seconds.

Comment: It is supposed to say "(no )input rec**ie**ved" which importantly obstructs golfing languages with dictionaries.

Comment: @Adám Actually that's a typo

Comment: @Phoenix Noooo!

Comment: Why do a=no then $a? is there a purpose? EDIT I got it I didn't read the question properly

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell, <s>97</s> 89 bytes

```
import System.Timeout
timeout(10^7)getChar>>=putStr.(++"input received").maybe"no "mempty
```

If `timeout` times out it returns `Nothing` and `Just Char` (`Char`, because we're using `getChar`) otherwise. This return value is converted to `"no "` or `""` by function `maybe "no " mempty`. Append `"input received"` and print.

Edit: @BMO suggested `maybe` and saved some bytes.

Comment: Doesnt seem to run correctly in ghci.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Within ghci you have to bind `g` with `let`: `let g Nothing="no ";g _=""`, then the function call `timeout....` works fine for me.

Comment: You can replace `g` by `maybe"no "(pure"")` which is shorter and you can even inline it - saving you 6 bytes.

Comment: @BMO: Nice! `mempty` instead of `(pure"")` is even shorter.

Comment: Very nice, that's really clever!

Answer (score 11):

## POSIX C99, <strike>71</strike> 63 bytes

```
main(){puts("no input received"+3*poll((int[]){0,1},1,10000));}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct pollfd pfd; 
  pfd.fd = STDIN_FILENO; 
  pfd.events = POLLIN;  
  puts("no input received"+3*poll(&pfd,1,10000));
}
```

Since `poll` will return 1 in case of success, we multiply the result by 3 and shift the string accordingly. Then, we use the fact that `struct pollfd` has the following layout:

```
     struct pollfd {
     int    fd;       /* file descriptor */
     short  events;   /* events to look for */
     short  revents;  /* events returned */
 };
```

and that `STDIN_FILENO` is `0`, `POLLIN` is `1` to replace `pfd` with `int pfd[] = {0,1}`, which we finally make a compound litteral (as allowed by C99).

Comment: You need to specify that this targets POSIX, as the `poll.h` header is not part of the C99 language standard.

Answer (score 8):

## Applescript, 113

Applescript doesn't really do reading from STDIN.  Hopefully a `display dialog` is acceptable here:

```bash
({"","no "}'s item((display dialog""default answer""giving up after 10)'s gave up as integer+1))&"input received"
```

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```apl
'no input received'↓⍨{3*⍨⎕RTL←10::0⋄3⊣⍞}
```

This is an anonymous tacit function which [needs a dummy argument to run](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12696/43319).

`'no input received'` the full string

`↓⍨` drop as many characters from the front of that as the number returned by the

`{` anonymous explicit function (`⍵` denotes the argument)

`⎕RTL←10` set **R**esponse **T**ime **L**imit to ten seconds

`3*⍨` raise that number (ten) to the power of three (a thousand means "all")

`::` upon those exceptions (all),

`0` return 0

`⋄` try:

`⍞` get input

`3⊣` discard that and instead return 3

`}` end of function (note that the argument `⍵` was never mentioned)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl](http://perl.org), <s>74</s> 67 bytes

```perl
$m="input received";$SIG{ALRM}=sub{die"no $m\n"};alarm 10;<>;say$m
```

#### Old Version

```perl
$m="input received";$SIG{ALRM}=sub{die "no $m\n"};alarm 10;<stdin>;say $m;
```

(Run via perl -M5.10.1 ...)

Comment: No trailing newline is necessary in output, so you can cut `\n`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Actually you don't need `-M5.10.1`. You can just substitute `-e` with `-E`. (if you needed `-M5.10.1`, you would have to add a penalty to your score)

Comment: @Phoenix, the `\n` is there because of [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)'s behavior: “If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline, the current script line number and input line number (if any) are also printed, and a newline is supplied.” So without it would display “no input received at -e line 1.”. But of course, it could be a literal line break in the string. Beside that, the spaces between `die` and `say` and their parameters are not needed. Same for the final `;`. And `<>` is enough to read from standard input.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I believe -M is a version flag, which makes it exempt from penalty.

Comment: If you `eval` the read from STDIN, you can avoid needing a `die` message. In fact, a runtime error works just as well: `$SIG{ALRM}=sub{&0};alarm 10;say'no 'x!eval'<>','input received'`.

Comment: 63: '$_="input received";$SIG{ALRM}=sub{die"no $m\n"};alarm 10;<>;say' (replace \n by literal newline)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>72</s>  66 bytes

```perl6
my $s='input received';Promise.in(10).then:{say "no $s";exit};get;say $s
```

[Try it with no input](https://tio.run/##HY3BSsQwFEX3/YrLWKjOoujGRcIsXDhaEBX1B8LkOQmTvpTkjRpKv71GV5dzD5c7UQq36wU@zYlgcM6UIM4IbKTMnUDKVAUXcZ6PTbu9e3vYD0/379ih3Q7PNQ7B5Ayl4DOGF6UeDdtAmBtgJHHR4kjyj0CIccKMD5fI2L54ChZLNUuz9Ezfeh0L2rzrPE9nQaID@S@ynX5NcfSZes@XN9dXvThiNWdTsOFYBxtNP14WXY/0X9vmdf0F)
[Try it with input](https://tio.run/##HY0xbsJAFER7n2LkWCJQWKGh2BVFCgiWohBBm2aFP/GK9dra/53EQr5MOAdn4gjOhmo0T5o3LQW3GB9wNCeCQccUIJURSN8S43b93ZBzze16gfEl2kDMkQeSLvgkmz3vXtbF62qPJbJZ8Rbj4AwzlIJlFFulNnHnCOcEqEmqpsQnyb0C6V3@4dPYhmTIPX3rse6R8XJifdtJPDqQ/aJyot9DU1um3PrH@dM0l4q8OrPpkfomDlJNP1YGHeX6n2Y8jn8)

```perl6
my$s='input received';start {sleep 10;say "no $s";exit};get;say $s
```

[Try it with no input](https://tio.run/##HY3NagIxFIX38xQHDQy4EN10McGFC38GpIW2LxDM1QnGJORe2waZZ58GV4fvfHBOouzfpjku5kYweDBlyGAENhKHViAlVRGKDC5cG7XYfh72/Wn3hQ3Uon@vcfaGGV0Hx@g/uu5ogvWEZwPcSYZocSV5IeBjTHjie8hk7LI48hZjNWMzLgP96uleFG9aF9JDkOlM7odsq1lMrhPsiRLWK82mYBYiFM80/TkZdb14tYqn6R8)
[Try it with input](https://tio.run/##HY1BisJAFET3OUURGwQXw7hxkcaFC2cMiIJu3TTmq8G20/T/UYPkMnoOz@QRYpNVUQ/qladgJ90AB3MmGNRMAXIyAmk8MT7v54KsrT7vF4wr4AMxRx5I6uASNZpt/v/y5XyLKdQoX8XYW8OMLEPJyNdZtog7S3gkwIXkVBU4kvQVSHv5zqWxtUn74@imu0ujeDosna8l/uypvFIx1CwmxBlbIo/xr2bTIHUVFKea7qW0Omp7qrjrvg)

```perl6
my $s = 'input received'; # base message

start {         # create a Promise with a code block
                # that is run in parallel
  sleep 10;     # delay for 10 seconds
  say "no $s";  # say ｢no input received｣
  exit          # exit from the process
}

get;            # get a line from the input
say $s          # say ｢input received｣
```

Comment: "my ess is input recieved -- promise in 10 then say 'no ess' and exit or get say 'ess'"

Comment: Can you remove the space between `start` and `{`?

Comment: @Phoenix That would be parsed as associative indexing on a sigilless variable named `start`, so no.

Comment: Your TIO links appear not to work anymore.

Comment: @Pavel, Fixed, just had to make the dummy test class a subtype of IO::Handle and call `.new` on it

Comment: You also don't need spaces before `$s`.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, <s>180</s> <s>171</s> <s>148</s> 131 bytes

```c#
()=>{var t=new System.Threading.Thread(()=>{System.Console.ReadKey();});t.Start();return(t.Join(10000)?"":"no ")+"input recieved";}
```

*Saved 17 bytes thanks to @VisualMelon.*

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Func<string> f = () =>
        {
            var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            });
            t.Start();

            return (t.Join(10000) ? "" : "no ") + "input recieved";
        };

        System.Console.WriteLine(f());
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `namespace` and not a `using` directive?

Comment: @Phoenix they would need a namespace anyway so they save all the bytes of the `using`

Comment: Why did you save the crucial part as an Action and execute it afterwards? I can't really see the question specifying this.

Comment: @Snowfire Because an `Action` is cheaper than a full program

Comment: Can save quite a bit by using the return value from `Thread.Join(int)`, (rid of `c`, lose braces, etc. etc.): `var t=new System.Threading.Thread(()=>System.Console.ReadKey());t.Start();return(t.Join(10000)?"":"no ")+"input recieved";` (VB.NET already seems to do this)

Comment: @VisualMelon Awesome didn't even know it returned a value haha!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes, it returns a value based on if it timed out. see vb.net sample below (although it's .net's idea, not vb.net's ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure on C#'s formatting for expontentiation, could you swap `10^4` out for `10000`?

Comment: @TaylorScott I can do `1e4` but that is a `double` and I'd need an `int` so I'd have to do `(int)1e4` :( Nice idea though

Comment: What about using a type literal suffix for `long` (`L`) or `uint` (`U`)? if this is implicitly converted or if `uint` extends `int` would it let you drop a byte? (ie use `1e4U`)

Comment: @TaylorScott Can't seem to get if to work

Comment: Well thats a shame :( - was worth the shot

Answer (score 5):

## TI-BASIC, <s>84</s> 77 bytes

-7 thanks to [@kamoroso94](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57013/kamoroso94)

```
:startTmr→T         //Start Timer, 5 bytes
:Repeat checkTmr(T)=10 or abs(int(.1K)-8)≤1 and 1≥abs(3-10fPart(.1K  //Loop until the timer is 10 seconds or a number key is pressed, 32 bytes
:getKey→K           //get key code, 4 bytes
:End                //end loop, 2 bytes
:"NO INPUT RECEIVED //Push string "NO INPUT RECEIVED" to Ans, 18 bytes
:If K               //If input was received, 3 bytes
:Disp sub(Ans,3,15  //Diplay "INPUT RECEIVED", 9 bytes
:If not(K           //If no input, 3 bytes
:Ans                //Display "NO INPUT RECEIVED", 1 byte
```

Waits until a number is pressed.

I am trying to figure out how to golf the sequence `{72,73,74,82,83,84,92,93,94}`. It is taking up a lot of space.

Comment: If you want to wait for just any key, then `Repeat K or 10=checkTmr(T` would do.

Comment: Also, the last 4 lines could be shortened to
`:4-3not(K:sub("NO INPUT RECEIVED",Ans,18-Ans`

Comment: @bb94 I don't really want to wait for just any key, since not all of those would actually input a character. It would be like waiting for the `Shift` key on a computer. Also, shortening the last 4 lines with your method actually gives the same byte count as mine. I like your method, though.

Comment: You could check for any key that isn't 21 or 31.

Comment: After `or` in your repeat statement, use this instead for -7 bytes: `abs(int(.1K)-8)≤1 and 1≥abs(3-10fPart(.1K`

Answer (score 4):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

<sup>*2 bytes saved by [Blauhirn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125332//125348?noredirect=1#comment308732_125348)*</sup>

```
InputBox,o,,,,,,,,,10
s:=ErrorLevel?"no ":
Send %s%input received
```

AHK has a built-in timeout for input boxes.
I tried to get clever and use `!o` instead of `ErrorLevel` but that fails if the user inputs a falsey value.
Almost half of the answer is just the command names and fixed text.

Comment: What are all the commas for?

Comment: @Phoenix Probably eliding arguments to InputBox

Comment: @Phoenix `Timeout` is almost the last parameter: `InputBox, OutputVar [, Title, Prompt, HIDE, Width, Height, X, Y, Font, Timeout, Default]`

Comment: two chars shorter: `s:=errorLevel?"no ":`

Comment: @Blauhirn Gah! I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## NodeJS, <s>105</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @apsillers*
*-2 bytes by moving `console.log()` into `exit()`*

```js
with(process)stdin.on('data',r=x=>exit(console.log((x?'':'no ')+'input received'))),setTimeout(r,1e4)
```

Run by saving to a file and running it with node or run it straight from the command line by doing `node -e "<code>"`

Comment: @apsillers Yup, good catch.

Comment: @apsillers I was about to edit again to actually move the `console.log()` call into the parameter of `exit()`. That's two less, now.

Answer (score 4):

## Go, 149 bytes

```
package main
import(
."fmt"
."time"
."os"
)
func main(){
o:="input received"
go func(){Sleep(1e10)
Print("no "+o)
Exit(0)}()
i:=""
Scan(&i)
Print(o)}
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, <s>86</s> <s>84</s> <s>82</s> 79+11 = <s>97</s> <s>95</s> <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```js
setTimeout(oninput=_=>i.remove(alert(`${i.value?"":"no "}input received`)),1e4)
```

```html
<input id=i
```

- 2 bytes saved thanks to [apsillers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7796/apsillers) pointing out that I'm dumb!

---

### Try it

Requires a closing `>` on the `input` in order to work in a Snippet.

```js
setTimeout(oninput=_=>i.remove(alert(`${i.value?"":"no "}input received`)),1e4)
```

```html
<input id=i>
```

Comment: 1e5 is 100,000 or 100 seconds, 1e4 is 10 seconds

Comment: Oops! Well spotted, thanks, @PunPun1000

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter to write `10` instead of `1e4`?

Comment: @musicman523, `10` would be 10 milliseconds, the challenge challenge specifically says 10 *seconds*, which is 10000 milliseconds, hence `1e4`.

Comment: My bad, forgot that `10 != 1e4` because I'm a fool

Comment: @musicman523 Easily done if your language's lowest measurement of time is in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `f=` is doing in `oninput=f=...`; you don't use `f` anywhere. Can it simply be removed?

Comment: @apsillers, the only reason it's there is because I'm dumb! :D The event handler was originally outside the timer and I simply forgot to remove the `f=` when I moved it inside. Will update when I get back to a computer.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 158 bytes

```
import os,threading as t,time
def k(t=10):time.sleep(t);print("No input received"[(10-t)//3:]);os.kill(os.getpid(),t)
t.Thread(None,k).start()
if input():k(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

### VB.Net - 174 bytes

```
Module M
Sub Main()
Dim t=New Threading.Thread(Sub()Console.Read()):t.Start():Console.WriteLine(If(t.Join(10000),"","no ") & "input received"):End
End Sub
End Module
```

COBOL version coming tomorrow ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage is of combining lines with `:`. That takes the same number of bytes as a line break, so it just decreases readability without improving the golf score.

Comment: @CodyGray I believe that the `:` line break substitution may be so that the treading call may be declared inline without repeating - but that said I am not positive, my main language is VBA which does not support threading or reading from the <strike>console</strike> immediate window asside from at the time of function definition or calling :P

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, <s>100</s> <s>89</s> <s>83</s> 71 bytes

```
import pty
print("no input received"[3*any(pty.select([0],[],[],10)):])
```

First try at golfing.

-4 for `any()`, -7 for slicing, thanks @user2357112!

-6, get `select()` from `pty` instead of `select`.

Comment: You can cut some bytes out by slicing a `"no input received"` string: `"no input received"[3*bool(...):]`.

Comment: You can also use `any(...)` instead of `bool(...[0])`.

Comment: -New User: "on Windows it throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'"

Comment: The [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) module is only available on linux platforms, but I'm only using it because its name is short and it makes `select` available. [Version 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/125491/2) probably works better on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 110 bytes

```
$s1=date;while(![console]::KeyAvailable-and($i=((date)-$s1).seconds-lt10)){}
"{0}input received"-f(,'no ')[$i]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch 2/3.x, 41 points ([Explanation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/golfing-in-scratch))

[image: Impatient timer]

1: When GF clicked

1: ask [] and wait

1 + 14 chars: say [input received]

1: stop [all v] (note: since "all" was its default setting I counted the block as 1)

1 + 2 digits: wait (10) seconds

1 + 17 chars: say [no input received]

1: stop [all v]

Comment: Welcome to PCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch 3.0 (scratchblocks3 syntax), 129 bytes/40 [points](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/golfing-in-scratch)

Beats @Syntax Error's answer by 1 point, but loses to it by 8 bytes.

```
define
broadcast[w v
ask[]and wait
say[input received
stop[all v
when I receive[w v
wait(10)secs
say[no input received
stop[all v
```

Ungolfed:

```
define // custom blocks (functions) do not need names. functions are shorter than programs when counting bytes, because programs that run require "when gf clicked"
broadcast [w v]
ask [] and wait // contrary to what the name of this block would suggest, there is no "ask [] (without waiting)" block - this is why the broadcast is necessary to allow other blocks to run while this block is waiting
say [input received]
stop [all v]

when I receive [w v]
wait (10) secs // although the actual block reads 'seconds', 'secs' is valid in scratchblocks syntax
say [no input received]
stop[all v]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 99 bytes

```tcl
after 10000 {set () no}
vwait [fileevent stdin r {gets stdin (x)}]
puts [lappend () input received]
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC 3, 74 bytes

"Accepts input" by waiting for any button press (that should count as input.)

```
M=MAINCNT@L
N=MAINCNT-M>599CLS?"NO "*N;"INPUT RECEIVED
ON N+BUTTON()GOTO@L
```

Comment: Output should be "(no) input received", not "INPUT (NOT) RECEIVED"

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 43 + 6 = 49 bytes

```
a/!/i0(?\~"input recieved"r>o<
o "\?:-1/r"n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P1FfUT/TQMM@pk4pM6@gtEShKDU5M7UsNUWpyC7fhitfQSnG3krXUL9IKQ@o@L9uYomegQUA)

+5 for the `-t.08` flag, which sets the tick to 0.08 seconds, and +1 for the `a` flag, which counts whitespace and skipped instructions as ticks.

The program checks for input about once every second, and exits the loop if input is detected. If input is not received, it exits the loop from the bottom, appending `no` to the beginning of the string. The initial `/` is to ensure that the last check for input is exactly on the 10 second mark.

It then takes about 5-6 seconds to print the string itself.

Comment: You can use a single flag, `-at.08` to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 1.4+, 284 bytes

```
import static java.lang.System.*;public class X{public static void main(String[]x){new Thread(){public void run(){try{Thread.sleep(10000L);}catch(Exception e){}out.print("no input recieved");exit(0);}}.start();new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();out.print("input recieved");}}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class InputAndWait {
    public static void main(String[] x) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000L);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                out.print("no input recieved");
                exit(0);
            }
        }.start();
        new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        out.print("input recieved");
    }
}
```

---

Please don't suggest Version-specific Java improvements, this is a generic Java answer that works in all currently stable Java Environments (1.4 and above).

---

Very freaking wordy... The catch is required, can't throw it. System import shaves off like 5 bytes... Overloading is also wordy, so it ends up a wordy poorly-golfed-looking mess.

Comment: Does it have to be `10000L` and not `10000`? I thought ints cast to longs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 78 bytes

Longer than I expected. See comments for "no input recieved" TIO link.

```julia
s="input recieved"
Timer(x->(show("no "*s);exit()),10)
readline(STDIN)
show(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/2FYpM6@gtEShKDU5M7UsNUWJKyQzN7VIo0LXTqM4I79cQykvX0FJq1jTOrUis0RDU1PH0ECTqyg1MSUnMy9VIzjExdNPkwussljz/38A)

Comment: It doesn't block on TIO because it's reading from a file. It hits EOF and finishes instantly. If you pipe a process that never emits newlines into the program on TIO, it'll block: https://tio.run/##JcqxDoIwEIDhvU9x6ULPCNXFxejk4uIiowvaSzgDLekVReO7V4Pb/yX/W9qcXyTwgRShdFBcfPGDDUOy97HjZmOv7P8JFfthTFXikLPs9CyIdGN6kNOq5p6imcq9kTY8jfYB9EJwSxMng7hcr1BFalzHnsy5PhxPqOZT8As

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
M=MAINCNT
WHILE!I*M>MAINCNT-600I=INKEY$()>"
WEND?"no "*!I;"input received
```

Takes 1 character of input.

And a 39 byte solution which probably isn't valid (doesn't actually accept text input, just has an <kbd>OK</kbd> button that you can press)

```
?"no "*!DIALOG("",,,10);"input received
```