# Read a password: on mobile!

Tags: code-golf, string

Thanks to [MD XF's recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125635/read-a-password), we can now read passwords in many different languages! The problem is, now we need to port our applications to mobile devices, and they do password entry a little differently.

## Challenge

- Read a string from the keyboard.
- Each time a character`k` is entered, display it for a short time interval.
- After the time interval has passed OR the user has entered another character, replace `k` with some character `c`.

## Rules

- `c` must be constant; it must be the same character.
- `c` can be any visible character (i.e. it cannot be a newline, space, tab, or unprintable).
- `c` can't be based on any inputted `k`; `c` must be defined/constant
  before the first `k` is read.
- `c` must be the same every time the program is run.
- `c` can be one of the values given as `k` if by accident, as long as all other rules are followed.
- You must print `k` in realtime. As soon as the user enters a new `k`, you must display it immediately.
- `k` should be visible to the end user before being changed to `c`; the time interval shall not be less than 0.5 seconds.
- `k` should be replaced by `c` within a reasonable time; the time interval shall not exceed 5 seconds.
- As soon as a new character is entered, whether or not the time interval has expired, you should replace `k` with `c` and use the entered key as the new `k` immediately.
- It is acceptable to clear and redraw the screen each time you need to change a character.
- You may use any reasonable methods of input and output as long as all other rules are followed.
- You may assume that the number of characters inputted is never longer than the terminal/graphical window width.
- If using a terminal, your program should terminate after a newline is entered or EOF is reached.
- Your program should function as outlined here on both mobile and other environments.
- Your program may assume that the input will only contain printable characters (letters, numbers, symbols) and possibly a terminating newline (no backspace, arrow keys, delete, etc).
- Your program may terminate when Ctrl+C is pressed.
- You may terminate your program by closing a window, if your program launches one.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins!

## Example

Here is an example of what it should look like. Note this is recorded on a mobile platform, but should also work on a desktop platform.

[image: password]

Comment: For those who can see deleted posts, [here is the Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12814/69054)

Comment: Which keyboard are you using in the video?

Comment: @BetaDecay the notification at the end states zenui keyboard

Comment: @BetaDecay It is in fact the ZenUI keyboard. Just curious, or does it matter?

Comment: @musicman523 Just curious :)

Comment: do i _need_ to redraw/clear the screen? can i just append a new line with the result?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista The idea is that you are updating the character after a short time (0.5 - 5 seconds), or after the next character is entered. You may either update the screen, or redraw it entirely. (So no, you cannot just append a new line with the result.)

Answer (score 4):

## HTML + JavaScript, 20+105 = 125 bytes

```
<input id=I oninput=v=I.value;s='*'.repeat(l=v.length-1);I.value=s+v[l];clearTimeout(I.t);I.t=setTimeout(`I.value=s+'*'`,1e3)
```

The delay between the entry of `k` and the letter becoming `*` is one second.

### JavaScript `oninput`, Formatted

```js
v=I.value;
s='*'.repeat(l=v.length-1);
I.value=s+v[l];
clearTimeout(I.t);
I.t=setTimeout(`I.value=s+'*'`,1e3)
```

### Test Snippet

Added the ending bracket (`>`) for better compatibility.

```html
<input id=I oninput=v=I.value;s='*'.repeat(l=v.length-1);I.value=s+v[l];clearTimeout(I.t);I.t=setTimeout(`I.value=s+'*'`,1e3)>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to terminate though!

Comment: @officialaimm The challenge states that only terminal applications need to have a way to terminate them.

Comment: Ah, silly me. Sorry.

Comment: On my browser `I.value` => `value` seems to work fine

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>186</strike> 224 bytes

Works only in windows.

```python
import os,time,msvcrt as m
i=s=x=0;t=time.clock
def v():os.system("cls")
v()
while 1:
 if m.kbhit():
  k=str(m.getch())
  if"\\r"in k:break 
  i+=1;x=1;v();print("*"*(i-1)+k[2]);s=t()
 if (t()-s>.6and x):x=0;v();print("*"*i)
```

Older version(186 bytes): The sleep was mandatory regardless of the speed at which key was pressed.

```python
import os,time,msvcrt
a=k=[];i=0;o=os.system
while 1:
 o("cls")
 if i:print("*"*(i-1)+a[i-1]);time.sleep(.6);o("cls");print("*"*i)
 k=str(msvcrt.getch())
 if"\\r"in k:break
 a+=k[2];i+=1
```

Comment: I don't think this quite meets all the criteria, specifically `As soon as a new character is entered, whether or not the time interval has expired, you should replace k with c and use the entered key as the new k immediately.` That being said, I can't test it since I don't run Windows, so let me know! You may find [this related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125332/impatiently-wait-for-input) helpful as a reference

Comment: I assumed the replacement from k to c was only graphical (which is fulfilled in my code). Did you also mean to change the stored value of k with c?

Comment: Nope, that's all there should be. Your time delay is .6 seconds - what happens if I type in two letters within .1 seconds of each other? Will you still sleep for 1.2 seconds? Again, sorry I can't test this myself - it might be worth posting a video of you running your code!

Comment: Modified. The newer version ensures new character can be thrown even before the previous character's time has not been out.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 133 bytes

Based on @officialaimm [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125910/38183).

```python
import time,msvcrt as m
k=T=0
s=p='\r'
while'\r'!=k:
 t=time.time();print s,
 if m.kbhit():k=m.getch();s=p+k;T=t;p+='*'
 if t-T>1:s=p
```

Comment: Woah, 90  bytes less!!! Would vote but my daily limit has been reached. Is there a way to check it(I only have python 3 on my pc)? Btw I dont see no clear screen, how is it managed?

Comment: @officialaimm by the `\r` in the print

Comment: I'll post a py3 variant when i get to my classroom

Comment: @officialaimm [this](https://pastebin.com/zJC2pw4R) should work, i'm on linux atm, so i can't test it

Comment: I checked it, It's working. (y)

Answer (score 0):

## HTML + JavaScript, 115 bytes

```html
<input id=I oninput="setTimeout(g=>g==I.value?I.value=0+g.slice(0,-1):0,1e3,I.value=I.value.replace(/.(?=.)/g,0))">
```